# IF Loop with multiple THEN statements in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm cobbling together a bit work for my job and, as I'm not a programmer by trade, am struggling with the below - any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a worksheet named 'Data' with information laid out as:

[image]

Columns E and F perform operations on the data in Columns B through D which is pasted in from an external source.

The figures in red are an example of how new data is pasted in. The function below checks for the first row with no value in Column E and the last row with a value in Column B. It then loops pasting the formula from E2 and F2 to all rows in that range.

I'm also trying to add an input box which asks the user for the date the information is received and enter that date into Column A in the same range.

I've put the below together, but it produces a Compile Error: Syntax error on the 'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 38) line.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub Paste_formula()

'Declare variables and set their types
Dim r As Range
Dim CurrRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StatementDate As Date

'Execute a series of statements relating to the 'Data' Worksheet
With Sheets("Data")
    'Set variable's values
    CurrRow = ActiveCell.Row
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    StatementDate = InputBox("Please enter the date of the statement in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy", "Statement Date")

    'For Loop which establishes the range for r being between the last row with Data in column E and the last row with Data in column B
        For Each r In .Range("B" & CurrRow & ":B" & LastRow)
        'If there is no value in
         If r.Value <> vbNullString Then r.Offset(0, 0) = r
         'Select Column A for any row between
         r.Offset(0, 0).Select
         'Enter the user's input into Cell A of row
         StatementDate = ActiveCell.Value
         'Then move to last column of row
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 38)
         ' ...select the last column of the row...
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 38).Select
         ' ...and paste the current selection
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         Next r
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: remove the offending row. It's not valid syntax and you're selecting the same range in the next statement.

Comment: What is the formula? There's a much easier way to paste an entire formula in one go for a range of cells e.g. `Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=B1+C1"` and Excel is clever enough to change the row for each depending if needed.

Comment: @teylyn - i've removed the row - and changed the line r.Offset(0,0).Select to r.Offset(0,-1).Select so that the cell in Column A is selected - and the code runs, but the date the user inputs isn't entered into the range in Column A

Thanks

Comment: @jamheadart - I'm not sure I could post the formula I'm actually using here - I've really simplified down the actual Data sheet but retained the broad principles. I've not seen that way of handling formula before though, could you go into more detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the numbers I took a guess at the formula applied - this doesn't answer your question but try this version of filling a range with a formula in one line only (no looping, copying or pasting)

```
Sub Fill_formula()

    'Declare variables and set their types
    Dim LastRowA As Long
    Dim LastRowB As Long
    Dim StatementDate As Date

    'Execute a series of statements relating to the 'Data' Worksheet
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        'Set variable's values
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        LastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        StatementDate = InputBox("Please enter the date of the statement in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy", "Statement Date")

        .Range("E" & LastRowA & ":E" & LastRowB).Formula = "=SUM(B" & LastRowA & ":D" & LastRowA & ")"
        .Range("F" & LastRowA & ":F" & LastRowB).Formula = "=B" & LastRowA & "-C" & LastRowA & "-D" & LastRowA

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for that.

But the Data sheet is actually much much bigger than the one in the example (it runs to a couple of thousand rows and contains personal data which is why I can't post it) which is why I've had to use Loops.

Comment: You'll not need loops if the new data is added at the end each time, doesn't matter of the size, you just need the start row and the end row and Excel can fill the whole lot - You could even just refresh the formula from A1:A10000 if you wanted - I do it all the time with fairly complex formulae, it might just be a bit of a headscratcher to concatenate the start and end row if the formulae is highly nested with lots of references.

Comment: Okay, I'll test your solution and figure out the concatenation stuff for the formula in my sheet.

I may be some time (in between doing the above and other work), could I re-comment later with any issues I have/let you know how I get on?

Thanks

Comment: Sure thing - it's worth a go because it's so much quicker, neater, less prone to error vs. selecting/copying/pasting etc

Comment: The formula is a very long IF function that won't fit in the line in VBA. I'd need to re-think and re-do the majority of the Worksheet to make this method work.

Comment: Oh well - there's also `Sheet1.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A11"), Type:=xlFillCopy` method where you can define the range as the last row with the formula down to the last row with a new entry..

Comment: I've edited the above to provide the general version of the solution I've made using your suggestion.

Thank you for your help.